# Embarcadero TThread: Pass TThreadMethod in C++

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder-xe8

Edit: 
Now that I have a better idea of what is going on, I think I can better phrase this question so it is more useful.

I am trying to replicate the following delphi code in C++

```
TThread.Queue(nil, 
    procedure
    begin
        LogMessage("test");
    end
    );
```

The purpose of the code is to call a method which updates a `TMemo` on a form in a thread safe manner.  Here is the C++ version of the method I am trying to call with `Thread.Queue`

```
void __fastcall TClientForm::LogMessage( String message )
{
    MemoLog->Lines->Add( message );
}
```

Because I am using a BCC32 compiler without CLANG enhancements, using a Lambda is not an option.  Instead according to [this documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B) I need to create a class which inherits from `TThreadProcedure` which overrides the `Invoke()` method to do the work I need done.  Then I can pass an instance of that class into `TThread::Queue`.

I created the following class which inherits `TThreadProcuedure` and contains an invoke method.

```
class TMyThreadProcedure : TThreadProcedure
{
    void __fastcall Invoke( String message );
};
```

However, since `TThreadProcedure` is an abstract class, I cannot simply create an instance of it to pass into `TThread::Queue`.  What is the proper way to inherit from `TThreadProcedure` and define a function to be called when I pass an instance of my class into `TThread::Queue`?

Comment: It's in the docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B

Comment: Thank you!  Ive read through this a couple of times now, but I am still not understanding what to do here :(

Comment: You haven't shown any C++ code at all. You haven't shown the method you want to call. Your Delphi example's anon method seems pointless. Do you need a lambda?

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details.  My first thought was to use a lambda. However, I am using the BCC32 compiler which I believe does not have the enhanced CLANG features required for lambda.

Comment: The documentation is very clear on this. You have to either 1) derive a class that implements the appropriate interface (in this case, `TThreadProcedure`) overriding the `Invoke()` method to do your desired work, and then you can pass an instance of that class to `TThread::Queue()`, or 2) in the C++11 compilers only, you can use a lambda in place of an anonymous procedure.  Either way, the documentation shows you exactly what to do, so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: `_di_TThreadProcedure` is a `DelphiInterface<T>` smart wrapper, `TThreadProcedure` is the actual interface.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have created a class which derives from TThreadProcedure, but since it is an abstract class, how do I create an instance of it to pass into `TThread::Queue()`?

Comment: @JamesHogle: As I said, `TThreadProcedure` has an `Invoke()` method that your class must implement. Did you look at the documentation? It has an example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did, I am still very new to this language so I am having a hard time piecing it all together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the documentation:

[How to Handle Delphi Anonymous Methods in C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B)

You have two choices:

1. derive a class <sup>1</sup> that implements the appropriate interface (in this case, `Classes::TThreadProcedure`), overriding the `Invoke()` method to do your desired work.  You can then pass an instance of that class to `TThread::Queue()`.  For example:

   ```
   class TLogMessageRef : public TCppInterfacedObject<Classes::TThreadProcedure>
   {
   private:
       TClientForm *form;
   public:
       TLogMessageRef(TClientForm* _form) : form(_form) {}
       INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN(TInterfacedObject);

       void __fastcall Invoke()
       {
           form->LogMessage("test");
       }
   };

   TThread::Queue(NULL,
       Classes::_di_TThreadProcedure(
           new TLogMessageRef(this)
       )
   );
   ```

   (<sup>1</sup> the use of [`TCppInterfacedObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TCppInterfacedObject) and `INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN` is covered elsewhere in the documentation: [Inheritance and Interfaces](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Inheritance_and_Interfaces#IUnknown_and_IInterface))

   The documentation also provides a reusable `TMethodRef` class to help with the implementation, if you need to use anonymous methods/procedures in multiple places of your code:

   [Using a Functor (Function Object)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B#Using_a_Functor_.28Function_Object.29)

   For example:

   ```
   struct LogMsg
   {
       TClientForm* form;
       LogMsg(TClientForm *_form) : form(_form) {}
       void operator()()
       {
           form->LogMessage("test");
       }
   };

   typedef TMethodRef<Classes::TThreadProcedure, LogMsg, void> MyMethRef;

   TThread::Queue(NULL,
       Classes::_di_TThreadProcedure(
           new MyMethRef(
               LogMsg(this)
           )
       )
   );
   ```
2. in the [Clang-based C++11 compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Clang-based_C%2B%2B_Compilers) only, you can use a C++ lambda anywhere an anonymous procedure/method is expected:

   ```
   TThread::Queue(NULL, 
       [this]() -> void { LogMessage("test"); }
   );
   ```

Comment: Could you explain how this overrides the `Invoke()` method?  Is the `struct LogMsg` an example of a Functor, like is described in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses

Comment: Look at the `TMethodRef` class provided in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B). It derives from the specified interface and overrides the `Invoke()` method to call the specified functor.  And yes, in this case, `LogMsg` is a functor (hence its `operator()`).